# In the phrasal verb 'put up', what is the meaning of 'up'?

Tags: prepositions

In the dictionary, I wrote that 'up'means 'up,perfectly'.
Then what is the meaning of 'up' in this sentence below?
'I put up at the cheap hotel.'

Comment: Phrasal nouns often have prepositions that don't actually _mean_ anything on their own: "give up," "give in," find out," etc.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "put up" refers being `lodged` or `placed` at the cheap hotel. The word "up" doesn't stand on its own; it's the phrase "put up" together, that means something special.

It also is primarily only used to refer to a temporary condition of placement.

Comment: Of course, a farmer might "put up hay", but that has a somewhat different meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks Never heard that phrase ... does it mean to stow it in a barn? Or to gather it?

Comment: Not being a farmer (just having been near them for much of my life), I don't have enough contextual clues to know precisely what it entails, but I've always assumed that the "put up" referred to storing the hay in the loft of a barn.  But the term could have originated, eg, from piling the hay in a haystack, or even from first stacking it in small sheaves/stacks in the field for drying.

Answer (score 1):

It may have been modelled in analogy to: to put up a friend for the night meaning:
to take up a friend in one's house for the night.
Maybe the use developed over:I put myself up (for the night) at a cheap hotel.

Comment: +1 for the second half. I'm pretty sure its short for that.